# Error in Nested map function React Native

Tags: react-native, nested-loops

I can't achieve to have two nested map with this below code i got `[Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.]`

```
const MyScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
const { fieldsBlock } = route.params;
// Iterate
const fieldItems = fieldsBlock.map((fieldBlock) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{fieldBlock.title}</Text>
      {fieldBlock.fields.map((field) => (
        <Text>{field.fieldValue}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  )
);
return (
  <View>
    {fieldItems}
  </View>
);
```

};

Only if i use one map function then it works but with the nested map function it give an error.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code that you have provided, check whether you have any unwanted spaces inside View tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that the problem is that if `fieldItems` results in an empty array, you will be trying to render nothing between View tags.

I suggest to change your code to render null if arrays are empty, like this

```js
const MyScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { fieldsBlock } = route.params;
  // Iterate
  const fieldItems = fieldsBlock.map((fieldBlock) => (
      <View>
        <Text>{fieldBlock.title}</Text> // <-- NOTE: because of this, view is not empty
        {(fieldBlock && fieldBlock.fields && fieldBlock.fields.length)
           ? fieldBlock.fields.map((field) => (
                <Text>{field.fieldValue}</Text>
             ))
           : null
        }
      </View>
    )
  );
  return (
    {fieldItems && fieldItems.length)
      ? <View>{fieldItems}</View> : null // <-- NOTE: In this case avoid render a view without children
    }
  );
};
```

It is fine to render this:

```
<View />
```

but not this:

```
<View>
</View>
```

Cheers!

Comment: yeah that was a problem actually, i was having problem in the array. thank you.